# Add or replace dash instead of nlb2r

Tags: php, html, css, prestashop-1.7

I have bellow code in Prestashop 1.7.3.
I want a dash-line after each nl2br.I remove br by css.

so all items are in a line.i want separate items by dashed(-)

```
<section class="product-features">
      <p class="page_heading">{l s='Data sheet' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</p>
        {foreach from=$product.grouped_features item=feature}
        <dl class="data-sheet flex_container">
          <dt class="name">{$feature.name}</dt>
          <dd class="value flex_child">{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br  nofilter}</dd>
        </dl>
        {/foreach}
    </section>

<style>
br{display: none;} 
</style>
```

Comment: Have you edited your question to change the desired result?  Is there something about my solution that is inadequate?  Perhaps a screenshot will help to clarify your question.

Comment: Oh,  am so sorry. I forgot to say that I remove the <br> by css

Comment: But that is of no consequence to my solution, correct?  Using css will be the cleanest way because 1. you don't need to introduce new dom elements 2. you literally want visual styling -- this is where css shines.

Answer (score 2):

I think, perhaps easiest would be to use css.  Just add a dotted border to the bottom of the `<dl>` tags.

```css
.product-features dl {
    border-bottom: dotted 1px red;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.product-features dl:last-child {
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px
}
```

```html
<section class="product-features">
        <p class="page_heading">{l s='Data sheet' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</p>
        
        <dl class="data-sheet flex_container">
          <dt class="name">{$feature.name}</dt>
          <dd class="value flex_child">{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br  nofilter}</dd>
        </dl>
        
        <dl class="data-sheet flex_container">
          <dt class="name">{$feature.name}</dt>
          <dd class="value flex_child">{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br  nofilter}</dd>
        </dl>
        
        <dl class="data-sheet flex_container">
          <dt class="name">{$feature.name}</dt>
          <dd class="value flex_child">{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br  nofilter}</dd>
        </dl>
    </section>
```

I you don't want the final `<dl>` to have a bottom border, just turn it off.

p.s. How foolish of me not to use condensed syntax and leave my answer open to a slight refinement.  Of course, you can use `border-bottom: dotted 1px red;`

Answer (score 0):

`Border-bottom` is simple way

```css
.product-features dl {
    border-bottom: dotted 1px black;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="product-features">
        <p class="page_heading">{l s='Data sheet' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</p>
        
        <dl class="data-sheet flex_container">
          <dt class="name">{$feature.name}</dt>
          <dd class="value flex_child">{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br  nofilter}</dd>
        </dl>
        
        <dl class="data-sheet flex_container">
          <dt class="name">{$feature.name}</dt>
          <dd class="value flex_child">{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br  nofilter}</dd>
        </dl>
        
        <dl class="data-sheet flex_container">
          <dt class="name">{$feature.name}</dt>
          <dd class="value flex_child">{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br  nofilter}</dd>
        </dl>
    </section>
```

Comment: Wow, your advice looks eerily familiar to my advice that was posted 5 minutes earlier -- and uses my exact snippet.  Poor form.  What are you trying to pull?

Comment: @mickmackusa Not tring to pull anything enhanced your answer only when we can do with simple one line why we need 3 different line.

Comment: My mistake. There I have fixed it.  Next time just leave me a comment rather than copy 99% of my answer and condense the declaration syntax (with the same effect).